# Resize views when menubar autohides/appear in fullscreen mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen, menubar

I'm working on an OSX app that supports a fullscreen mode.

The window is generated from a nib file but everything else is handled programmatically.

When I goes in fullscreen mode, my views resize properly but when the menu bar appear/disappear, setFrame don't get called for either the contentView or my own views. I'd to be notified

Is there a delegate to implement to catch those notifications? Or do I have to subclass NSWindow and find out how Safari handles its menu bar by reversing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I could at least get ride of the dirty gray bar at the top of the screen by subclassing the window's content view and add the following code to the setFrame method, before call super:

```
//isFullscreen
if(([self.window styleMask] & NSFullScreenWindowMask) == NSFullScreenWindowMask)
{
    frameRect.size.height = self.window.frame.size.height;
    frameRect.size.width = self.window.frame.size.width;
}
```

The window get resized to the screen size before setFrame get called, so we can use its size to update frameRect to window's size.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I don't understand how this solved it. I'm not even sure how to catch the "menubar-did-show" event. Can you shed some light?

Comment: Basically, the window resizes at the size of the screen, but because of some animations (I guess), it resizes the content is a way to keep space for the menu bar, for animating it, then 'forget' to notify the content of the window this is not the final size. Using this trick I force the content view to stick to the size of the whole window.

Comment: So `setFrame` is called whenever the window changes size? And then you simply change the height of the window when the window size changes in fullscreen mode, which only occurs when the menu bar is auto displayed?

Comment: Yep, the size of the content of the window shouldn't change when in fullscreen mode (except when you change the active screen), so you can overwrite the height you receive

Comment: Can I see your full setFrame method?

Comment: This is odd... I've subclassed my NSView, implemented `setFrame`, but it's only being called once, when the window is loaded. It's not being called when the window changes size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54813/discussion-between-taiki-and-charlie).

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see some code, how exactly "your views resize properly".

But next info might help:

When a window goes fullscreen it occupies entire screen after the end of the fullscreen animation. The main menu bar shows over the window ("above" in sense of z-ordering). So when main menu bar shows/hides frame of your window and content view don't change.
Also note, that -[NSScreen visibleFrame] returns unoccupied frame. And it will not return whole screen frame until the end of the fullscreen animation.

Comment: The fullscreen is mostly handled as a classical resizing, so there is not much code to show, mostly tricks to propagate the resize to the whole view hierarchy. It seems responding to windowDidEnterFullScreen and resizing the content view does the trick. However, two problems remain: there is a weird behavior at startup, windowDidEnterFullScreen get called when the animation is still in progress (height + origin.y = screen height - MB height); and during the animation, visibleFrame still return the area available minus the menu bar, so when windowDidEnterFullScreen get called, I'm still short.

Comment: Plus I still can't easily handle how the GUI react when menu bar appear